# Arguing / Pretending as an Opponent Speaker

Tags: logic, terminology

What do you call a person or the strategy where the speaker acts as the opponent to know the issue at hand better (as an opponent). For instance, a Vegan (person X) can argue with another Vegan, pretending as a non-vegan, his actual motive is to understand veganism better, he actually wants to consolidate his position as a vegan. This person X wants to clear all his doubts and questions answered about veganism, hence he acts as an opponent in the discussion. Is there any name for such a strategy or act?

Comment: Devil's advocate?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think you are right (I will accept the answer later).

Comment: It depends upon the culture. Different cultures to this in their argumentation and have different terms for it.

Comment: can u explain a bit more plz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Devil's advocate.

From Dictionary.com: a person who advocates an opposing or unpopular cause for the sake of argument **or to expose it to a thorough examination**.